# Geometry Nodes - Image texture mapping. How to?

Tags: image, geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

How to manipulate an image texture mapping in geometry nodes?
For example to use "generated" or "object" mapping, like in shader editor, also how to scale a texture

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Object** coordinate space is the default space in geometry nodes:

[image]

**UV** is default coordinate space **for the Image Texture node** in the shader, but you can pass it to the geometry nodes as input:

[image]

**Generated:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! But how to scale it?

Comment: oh, it's position * vector multiply before image - figured that out