# How to make instances appear periodically around an object

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances, vector

I'm experimenting with geometry nodes and I'm stuck with something I think is pretty simple but can't find a way. I just want the instances to appear around the cilinder growing and shrinking the same way I can rotate the white part of that cilinder in the shading editor

[image: With this setting i can make the bright side rotate around the object, i want to do the same with instances on geometry nodes, making them grow and shrink around the cilinder, any ideas?]

[image: This is what I came up with in geometry nodes, but it's not working]

Comment: Hello and welcome. That is not Geometry Nodes. You are only showing us the Shader Node Editor.

Comment: Hi! I know, it was just to give an idea of what I wanted to do, I've added a screen of the same thing in geometry nodes

Comment: Hey is it ok if the gradient is not this specific one? A similar result can be generated using the proximity node with a line for the proximity.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the polar-angular coordinate easily using *Gradient Texture: Radial*, which outputs a normalized value 0..1, with a sudden change from 0 to 1, which you can fix in a *Color Ramp* (*Math: Ping Pong* would work too and be more performant…). Then you can add current frame to animate the offset, and take fraction to keep it in the 0..1 range, but also divide the offset so it doesn't rotate as fast as a beacon on cocaine:

[image]

You could (since B3.6) copy-paste the *Color Ramp* branch to a shader, except shaders don't have *Scene Time* node [image], so you need to emulate it with a `frame` driver:

[image]

Keep in mind *Texture Coordinate* node also had to be added, because *Gradient Texture* has a different default coordinate in shader and geometry nodes. See: [Geometry Nodes - Image texture mapping. How to?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254256/60486)

[image]