# Mapping gradient texture coordinates in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

I'm using Blender to create stylized landscape panoramas. I have a Digital Elevation Model (DEM) that I'm using as a height map in an image texture shader node to displace a plane (using **Cycles Experimental Feature Set** for the **Adaptive Subdivision Surface**) based on the methodology documented [here](https://somethingaboutmaps.wordpress.com/2017/11/16/creating-shaded-relief-in-blender/). I'm further modifying the underlying height map using a gradient texture and RGB Curves to dynamically tilt/roll the plane towards the camera.
[image]

Now that I have terrain, I'm using Geometry Nodes to disperse trees across the landscape. Seeing as my displacement only takes place in the Shader I've attempted to replicate my terrain displacement by referencing [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254256/geometry-nodes-image-texture-mapping-how-to), which was super helpful for mapping my DEM image texture, **but I cannot wrap my head around the mapping of the gradient texture** in the Geometry Nodes editor. My trees clip through the landscape :( here's my [blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UttT3wqIRuIO8e_uc_lVeZLi6NBegN_w/view?usp=sharing).
[image]
[image]

Comment: GN questions are very popular, if your questions is well asked, read here how to do it: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask . You didn't even show us your GN node tree. So how should we know how you made it? and help you? Pls provide blend file so we can check it out. thx.

Comment: Rookie mistake on my part, had the screenshot and failed to attach it. My apologies @Chris. I've updated the post with the GN node tree and attached the blend file.

Comment: I have just tested this with your file and it works exactly as you would expect: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJYuq.jpg Can you please check this again and update your question accordingly?