# Blender 4 - Geometry nodes - sample texture to populate points on surface

Tags: geometry-nodes, texture-painting

trying to sample a texture, as I paint the applied diffuse texture, points are indeed placed on the main mesh but they are not placed where I painted.

I also try to filter by color. **I expect the points to be populated only where I paint.**
Yeah I know I can use weight painting but I need a more flexible workflow

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: [Geometry Nodes - Image texture mapping. How to?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/254256/60486)

Comment: there is not texture coordinates node, hence the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geometry Nodes - Image texture mapping. How to?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254256/geometry-nodes-image-texture-mapping-how-to)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to use Named Attributes

https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-4-geometry-nodes-sample-texture-to-populate-points-on-surface/1506606/3

[image]