Array of curves deformed by texture image
I want to generate geometry with curve to mesh, where the path along which the curve is extruded is displaced in one dimension according to the pixel value of an image. Let's assume the image texture has a black square in the middle, the deformed paths should look something like this:
---------
---------
---------
---___---
---___---
---___---
---------
---------
---------

for a 9x9 pixel image. (the mapping doesn't have to be 1:1, but I assumed it would be the easiest)
I've tried to find ways to split the image into rows of pixels, using the "deform curves on surface" geometry node, the displacement geometry node, vector math node etc. but I can't figure out a way how to map the texture onto the displacement of individual objects according to the corresponding row of pixels.
The cross-section of these shapes is important which is why I chose the route of "Curve to Mesh" but I'm certainly open to other approaches.
Edit: blend file attached. There is not much there yet. I managed to create an array of curves that I can use "curve to mesh" on. But I don't know how to proceed from the texture map. Obviously there is something missing at the red link.
Edit2: cleaned up the file & packaged the texture.
V2:


Hello and welcome Norbert, could you please post your .blend here: https://blend-exchange.com/
so we can really see where you are at?

Difficult to see anything , you didn't pack your image, please pack it or post it...
perhaps take a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254256/geometry-nodes-image-texture-mapping-how-to
and try this: https://blend-exchange.com/b/5WdaGE1X/

Thanks for the example. That looks exactly like what I'm trying to do! Will try to replicate it.

It seems my issue was with the PNG I used, since it was black and transparent without any other color... Thanks again for your help!

Your welcome, I didn't do much...

Actually, I have one more problem. I can't resize the image texture and have to adjust the size of my object accordingly. The only way I can find to resize a texture is with the Mapping and Texture coordinate nodes, which are not available in the geometry nodes. Do I have to through a "material" node setup to accomplish this? (sorry don't know the correct terminology yet)

Could you update your blend (with packed textures)?
